# C#: Trigger a bash script on OSX from Windows

Tags: c#, bash

I have  bash script that deletes a file and kills a process by it's name on the Mac. I've got a C# assembly running on windows that needs to trigger this process at a certain time.

What is a feasable way to use C# to connect to your OSX machine using it's IP address, and invoke a bash script (preferably storing the script on your Windows machine rather than the Mac?)

Answer (score 1):

Why does the Windows machine need to do it? You say that the process needs to be triggered at a certain time. You could schedule the script on the Mac using a cronjob without having to deal with ssh'ing from one machine to another.

Comment: The windows is a central hub that will run similar processes on other windows machines and other Mac machines. I'd like to keep the code that does this on this machine.

Comment: If that's the case, it seems like the easiest way to do it would be to host the script on the central Windows machine and have it ssh into each client machine to perform the task. I don't know if C# is the best solution for that. This isn't a programming challenge so much as an administrative challenge. Why not just use Cygwin or PuTTY to connect and run commands on each remote machine?